# Sum of List data in retrofit

Tags: android, arraylist, sum

hear is my JSON Response,I want to total of list price.Use retrofit framework to parse JSON.

```
{
   "price": [
    "11",
    "29"
]
}
```

Comment: Parse it and sum it. what's wrong?

Comment: [11, 29]   this type of data in my total. I want 40 how can I do?

Comment: this is tutorial https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrofit-android-tutorial-to-get-json-from-server/

Comment: You response type  is `JsonObject` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 int sum = 0;
    int price = gridValues.get(position).getPrice().size();

    for (int j = 0; j < price; j++) {
        String total =gridValues.get(position).getPrice().get(j);
        sum += Integer.parseInt(total);
    }
```

fetch data from list and set in adapter and in adepter I put above code and solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe your request return type is `JsonObject`. To get sum of your `price`  `JsonArray`, you need to loop through every object of it and sum it.

```
    JsonObject object = parse.parse(data).getAsJsonObject();

    JsonArray priceArray = object.getAsJsonArray("price");
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < priceArray.size(); i++) {
        total += priceArray.get(i).getAsInt();//reading (as int) each object of array
    }
    System.out.println("Total is " + total);
```